Get package.json version as a global variable in codemagic.yaml
I have a codemagic.yaml file and I'd like to read the version number out of package.json and expose it as a global CM_ENV variable named VERSION for scripts elsewhere in the file. Then I want to use it later in a script like:
npx @sentry/cli@latest releases -o [orgName] new -p [projectName] [projectNameString]@${$VERSION}

I've tried a few things:


echo "VERSION=${npm pkg get version --workspaces=false | tr -d \"}" >> $CM_ENV



echo "VERSION=${node -p \"require('./package.json').version\"}" >> $CM_ENV



echo "VERSION=${npm pkg get version | xargs}" >> $CM_ENV

When Codemagic runs a build, these lines always result in a "bad substitution" error. Hoping someone has some ideas, any thoughts appreciated



your idea is correct but you used ${ ... } when you should have used $( ... ) for command execution.
And yet another version is
echo "VERSION=$(jq '.version' package.json)" >> $CM_ENV

